# Why doesn't my discrete gate SR flip-flop work?

Tags: logic-gates, flipflop

[image: D flip flop using S R flip flop]

When I make a SR flip-flop using NAND gates and configured it as in the above circuit. Why does it simulate differently and is useless?

Here is the circuit I made:

[image: SR flip flop using nand gates]

Comment: `simulate differently and useless` -- What output was expected, and what did you obtain?

Comment: @MituRaj     I expect the output to be 0 1 0 1 0 1 whenever the clock activates same as the top circuit but the bottom circuit is giving me something else I don't understand in the simulation, I don't know if my app is the one that have problem. I just need someone to also test the circuit and tell me what I need to do for the bottom circuit to be same results as the top circuit

Comment: either the `S` or the `R` should be green

Comment: What simulator are you using?

Comment: @Mattman944   I am using icircuit app

Comment: Do you understand also that "delays" are also an important thing in this kind of circuit? Behavior can be changed when you use delay for each gate (or not). https://www.dropbox.com/s/aof9lhz70befiwd/JK%20-%20FF%20Nand%20gates%20v72.cir%20Capture.PNG?dl=0

Comment: Joseph: Add information in comments and anything else relevant that you know and a link to the simulator and flag moderators using "Flag" button under question. The question will then be reopened.

Answer (score 3):

The first schematic shows an edge triggered flipflop. On each rising clock edge the flipflop output changes state.
The second schematic holds a state as long as clock is low, but during clock high period it is either oscillating with a high frequency defined by the propagation delay of the gates, or it reaches an analog "half on" state.

The simulator paints half of a signal line green, an interesting approach to indicate "half on"?

CMOS inverter gates behave that way with direct feedback from output to input.

To build an edge triggered flipflop like the one in the first schematic from NAND gates, you need two RS flipflops, a master and a slave stage, and some additional gates for clock distribution.

EDIT: Just found such a NAND flipflop circuit at wikipedia:
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/37/D-Type_Flip-flop_Diagram.svg

Answer (score 1):

According to your simulator and assuming that green is high and grey is low, the output of NAND2 is simultaneously high and low.

Either you haven't got a proper connection or the simulator is [banjaxed](https://www.wordorigins.org/big-list-entries/banjax#:%7E:text=It%27s%20Irish%20slang%20meaning%20to,favorite%20of%20Flann%20O%27Brien.).